# Hide tabHost bar when keyboard shows in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-manifest, android-input-method

I create an app with tabhost bar with fragment, the problem is when I open the keyboard I would like to hide the tabhost bar.

[image]

So far I have put the code in Main Activity

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
// Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
  if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
      tabHost.setVisibility( View.GONE );       

   } 
  else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden ==Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
      tabHost.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
   }
  }
```

And in the mainfest.xml

```
<application
android:configChanges="keyboard" 

....
```

However, when I first time enter the app and press on the input box it does not show the tabhost bar. But when I open camera/ get photo from album / switch the tab and press on the input box it show the bar .

How to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: did you find your solution? i'm facing the same problem.